# how to convert String to ArryList in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins extendedChoice parameter allow user select multi choices at sametime. Eg.

```
'''Jenkins scripted pipeline--head extendedChoice params 

    properties ([
        parameters([
          extendedChoice(name: 'office_components',
                       defaultValue: 'outlook',
                       description: 'Muti choice, please select office components',
                       value: 'word,excel,ppt,outlook',
                       type: 'PT_CHECKBOX')
       ])
    ])

    '''
```

We can use "${office_components}" to get the value in Groovy pipeline. Here we suppose user selected "word,excel,outlook", i use:

```
'''Jenkins pipeline--body

    def selected="${office_components}" 
    println selected  //word,excel,outlook 
    println selected.getClass() // class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl

'''
```

**In a word, how to convert above "word,excel,outlook" to ["word","excel","outlook"]?**

Comment: I have answered your question. Let me know if it works for you. Also, if it does, it would be really nice if you accept my answer as a solution and upvote it.

Comment: `@markzhu` Please view the answer now.

Comment: Thanks Rajan resolved my issue. the answer is: listSelected = selected.toString().split(",")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `split(",")` as you would in Java.

So, the following should do the job for you.

```
listSelected = selected.toString().split(",")
println( listSelected.collect{"\"" + it + "\""} )
```

Comment: thank you. but it not works, get nothing.  Tried: def new_selected=selected.split(',').collect{it}, just get [word,excel,outlook], not i want ["word","excel","outlook"]. Pls help to check.

Comment: thanks @markzhu. I will update the answer as per your needs.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you Rajan so much. This works for me.

Comment: I clicked the √ in your answer left area. Accept your answer, Genius. Thanks again. Really appreciate it.